# Reactjs Update a single element in an array inside state

Tags: reactjs

I have a component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        cards: []
    };
}
```

Inside the this.state.cards array, for each card the data structure looks like:

```
{
  movie: v,
  ids: v.id,
  goodDeal: `Cheapest price is ... at ...`
}
```

Now, I need to merge another cards(say cards2) array into my current state.cards array:

```
componentDidMount(){
    cards2.map((v, i)=>{
       var existedCard = this.state.cards.find((cv, ci)=>{
           if(cv.code === v.code){
               return cv;
           }
       })

       if(existedCard){
          existedCard.ids += v.id;

          this.setState((prevState, pros)=> {
              // then update the state, but how?                   
          })
       }
       else {
          // add the new card into the current cards array
       }
    })
}
```

As you can see, if I found an card(newCard) in card2 which is also in card1(which is the state.cards), then I add the newCard.id into the existedCard.ids.
Then I want to call setState() to update the state.

But how?

Comment: use setState and pass in a function.  You can declare state changes separately from the component classes.  Basically take your merging of cards and create a function out of it and pass it into setState({})

Here is Dan's tweet regarding this.  https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/824308413559668744/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.freecodecamp.org%2Fmedia%2F1c4129e6d55a4cee7d1883e97f2d207e%3FpostId%3D374f30401b6b

Comment: @iceveda06 thanks :) the tweet you shared it very helpful(not for this question, but my another question) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.assign() is the solution for me.

```
            this.setState((prevState, props) => {
                return Object.assign({}, prevState, existedCard);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setState((prevState) => {/* method that returns nextState*/})` form.
To add the new object run

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  cards: prevState.cards.concat(existedCard)
}))
```

For update you would have to filter out the old object first

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  cards: prevState.cards.filter( card => card.id !== v.id).concat(existedCard)
}))
```

You can also use the spread operator if its is supported by your target (build) system.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  cards: [...prevState.cards, existedCard]
}))
```

Comment: Hi Moti, thanks for your answer. I have tried the spread operator, it does add the updated card into cards array, but it also add all other cards which are existed already into the state.cards array. I found another way to do it, will post it here.